# Display featured image only on hover of post title

Tags: css, wordpress, posts

Hi I am building a wordpress as per requirement of my client I need to show posts featured image only when hovering on post's title.So far I tried doing this by simple css in this way

```
li.wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured
{ 
    display:none;
}

li.wpp-post-title:hover .wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured 
{
    display:block;
}
```

but this doesn't made the trick can you help me achieving this by any other process thanks in advance.

Comment: ".wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured " is this a single class name ?

Comment: yes it belongs to single class

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the property of one element `wpp-thumbnail` from the event of other element `li.wpp-post-title:hover`, I think you have to use Javascript.

You should attach `onmouseover="OnMouseIn"` to the li.wpp-post-title element and write a function in java script file to handle that. Eg:

`function OnMouseIn (elememnt) {
     // find and assign the thumbnail object to a var
     // make thumbnail visible
}`

The CSS way of doing it would be setting the thumbnail as background of image of the title, using padding to align it and then displaying it on hover. 
Same as setting different background for navigation items on hover.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS there seem to be a couple of dots missing and it is hard to see the logic when the HTML is not provided. However, it's not so difficult to achieve this with CSS. Just make sure that the featured image is included in the frame with the title.

Example, following your CSS:

--- HTML ---

```
<li class="wpp-post-title">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <img class="wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured" src="[your-ft-img-url]" />
</li>
```

--- CSS ---

```
.wpp-post-title .wpp_featured { 
    display:none;
}

.wpp-post-title:hover .wpp_featured {
    display:block;
}
```

Note:

- While you may, it is not recommended to add the li.
- Likewise, you do not need to add all the classes of the featured image. One is enough.
- If you would need to add all classes for a different reason, you need to add dots in between instead of spaces.

So, then the CSS would look as followed:

```
.wpp-post-title .wpp-thumbnail.wpp_cached_thumb.wpp_featured  { 
    display:none;
}

.wpp-post-title:hover .wpp-thumbnail.wpp_cached_thumb.wpp_featured {
    display:block;
}
```

I hope that helps. GL!